# letsencrypt not creating acme-challenge

Tags: nginx, debian, lets-encrypt

Just following the simple instructions here (Debian 7 Wheezy with Nginx 1.8.x)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

`./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d sub.domain.com`

I see it creating the folder `.well_known` (under /var/www/html) but it does not create the `acme-challenge` folder (and the actual file underneath it) so on the http postback, I am getting `The client lacks sufficient authorization` because the file does NOT exist

How would I got about trying to track down why it won't create the

`/var/www/html/.well_known/acme-challenge/file`

file?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi did you got anything ? I am facing same problem

Comment: This happens when your server is not reachable from the Internet.  The letsencrypt servers need to be able to reach your server to complete the process.  So you may have to setup a tunnel, do some DMZ work, route your IP to your server, etc in order to get this to work.  So far, I have not found anything that works for this situation.  Currently, I am just using a self-signed certificate to silence the SSL errors.